# Wireshark dissector decoding 64bit hex

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm having trouble dissecting 64-bit hex and from what I'm reading the way to do this is using ProtoField.uint64.

I can see this decoding nicely in Wireshark without protofield, though it doesnt work for `uint64`.

```
-- declare our protocol
trivial_proto = Proto("triviala","trivial Protocol")

-- create a function to dissect it
function trivial_proto.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "TRIVIA"
    local subtree = tree:add(trivial_proto,buffer(),"Trivia Protocol Data")
    subtree:add(buffer(0,2),"Seq number: " .. buffer(0,2):uint())
    subtree:add(buffer(2,4),"Seq number: " .. buffer(2,4):uint())
    subtree:add(buffer(6,2),"no messages: " .. buffer(6,2):uint())
    --Doesnt work
    --subtree:add(buffer(8,8),"no messages: " .. buffer(8,8):uint64())

end
-- load the udp.port table
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
-- register our protocol to handle udp port
udp_table:add(20004,trivial_proto)
udp_table:add(20006,trivial_proto)
udp_table:add(20021,trivial_proto)
```

[Wireshark dissecting msgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORbrb.png)

When I try exactly the same thing, with the same pcap using ProtoField, I can see my message type "TRIVIA" in wireshark but nothing decoded in its subtree

```
-- declare our protocol
trivial_proto = Proto("triviala","Trivia Protocol")

local F = trivial_proto.fields

F.f_1 = ProtoField.uint8("triviala.sessnum","Session Number",base.HEX)
F.f_2 = ProtoField.uint32("triviala.seqnum","Sequence Number",base.HEX)
F.f_3 = ProtoField.uint8("triviala.nomsgs","Number Mesages",base.HEX)
F.f_4 = ProtoField.uint64("triviala.time","Date Time",base.HEX)


-- create a function to dissect it
function trivial_proto.dissector(buffer,pinfo,tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "TRIVIA"
    local subtree = tree:add(trivial_proto,buffer(),"Trivia Protocol Data")
    subtree:add(F.f_1, buffer(0,2))
    subtree:add(F.f_2, buffer(2,4))
    subtree:add(F.f_3, buffer(6,2))
    --subtree:add(F.f_4, buffer(8,8))
end
-- load the udp.port table
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
-- register our protocol to handle udp port
udp_table:add(20004,trivial_proto)
udp_table:add(20006,trivial_proto)
udp_table:add(20021,trivial_proto)
```

[Wireshark not dissecting msgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSqNw.png)

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `trivial_proto.fields` to `F`, not the other way around.

If you refer to the `fpm.lua` script that is available on the [Wireshark Lua/Examples](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples) wiki page, you will see that you need to do something like:

```
local F =
{
    f_1 = ProtoField.uint8("triviala.sessnum","Session Number",base.HEX)
    f_2 = ProtoField.uint32("triviala.seqnum","Sequence Number",base.HEX)
    f_3 = ProtoField.uint8("triviala.nomsgs","Number Mesages",base.HEX)
    f_4 = ProtoField.uint64("triviala.time","Date Time",base.HEX)
}

trivial_proto.fields = F

...

subtree:add(F.f_1, buffer(0,2))
subtree:add(F.f_2, buffer(2,4))
subtree:add(F.f_3, buffer(6,2))
```